# Is it possible to get the number of pixels below a specific pixel value in WebGL/OpenGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

```js
class WebGLUtils {
    getGLContext = (canvas, version) => {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.99;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.85;
        var gl = canvas.getContext(version ? 'webgl' : 'webgl2');
        const ext = gl.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float");
        if (!ext) {
            console.log("sorry, can't render to floating point textures");
        }
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.lineWidth(0.5);
        return gl;
    };

    clear = (gl) => {
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    };

    getShader = (gl, type, shaderText) => {
        var vfs = gl.createShader(type);
        gl.shaderSource(vfs, shaderText);
        gl.compileShader(vfs);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vfs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vfs));
        }
        return vfs;
    };

    getProgram = (gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) => {
        var program = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program, this.getShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, document.getElementById(vertexShader).text.trim()));
        gl.attachShader(program, this.getShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, document.getElementById(fragmentShader).text.trim()));
        gl.linkProgram(program);
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        }
        return program;
    };

    getPreCompiledProgram = (gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) => {
        var program = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(program, this.getShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader));
        gl.attachShader(program, this.getShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader));
        gl.linkProgram(program);
        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
        }
        return program;
    };

    createAndBindBuffer = (gl, relatedVertices) => {
        var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(relatedVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        return buffer;
    };

    createAndBindTexture = (gl, img, AR) => {
        var texBuffer = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texBuffer);
        if (img.width) {
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
        } else {
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, AR.width, AR.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
        }
        // set the filtering so we don't need mips
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
        return texBuffer;
    };

    createTextureAndFramebuffer = (gl, width, height, type, filter) => {
        const tex = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        if (type === gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE) {
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, type, null);
        } else {
            const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
            console.log(`can ${status === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ? "" : "NOT "}render to R32`);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R32F, width, height, 0, gl.RED, type, null);
        }
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filter);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filter);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
        gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
        return {tex: tex, fb: fb};
    };

    linkAndSendDataToGPU = (gl, program, linkedVariable, buffer, dimensions) => {
        var vertices = gl.getAttribLocation(program, linkedVariable);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertices);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertices, dimensions, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);
        return vertices;
    };

    sendDataToGPU = (gl, buffer, vertices, dimensions) => {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertices, dimensions, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);
    };

    sendTextureToGPU = (gl, tex, index) => {
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + index);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    };

    activateTextureByIndex = (gl, program, gpuRef, gpuTextureIndex) => {
        gl.useProgram(program);
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(program, gpuRef), gpuTextureIndex);
    }
};





var gl, utils, pseudoImg, img;
var rectCoords = [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
var texCoords = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
var pixelCount = 0;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    utils = new WebGLUtils();
    gl = utils.getGLContext(document.getElementById('canvas')); 
    var showProgram = utils.getProgram(gl, 'new-vs', 'show-fs');
    var pixelCountProgram;

    var vertexBuffer = utils.createAndBindBuffer(gl, rectCoords);
    utils.activateTextureByIndex(gl, showProgram, 'u_texture', 1);
    
    var checkPixels = (myFbi) => {
        gl.useProgram(showProgram);
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
        utils.sendTextureToGPU(gl, myFbi.tex, 1);
        gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(showProgram, 'pixelCount'), pixelCount/(img.width * img.height));
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    };

    var countPixels = (img, tex) => {
        var myFBi = utils.createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, 1, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, myFBi.fb);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
        var fragmentShaderText = document.getElementById('pixelcount-fs').text.trim();
        fragmentShaderText = fragmentShaderText.replace('{imageWidth}', 'imageWidth='+img.width);
        fragmentShaderText = fragmentShaderText.replace('{imageHeight}', 'imageHeight='+img.height);
        pixelCountProgram = utils.getPreCompiledProgram(gl, 
            document.getElementById('new-vs').text.trim(), fragmentShaderText);
        utils.activateTextureByIndex(gl, pixelCountProgram, 'u_texture', 0);
        gl.useProgram(pixelCountProgram);
        utils.linkAndSendDataToGPU(gl, pixelCountProgram, 'vertices', vertexBuffer, 2);
        utils.sendTextureToGPU(gl, tex, 0);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        return myFBi;
    };

    var showTexture = () => {
        var tex = utils.createAndBindTexture(gl, img);
        var myFbi = countPixels(img, tex);
        //showProgram
        checkPixels(myFbi);
    };

    var checkGPU = () => {
        showTexture();
    };

    var checkCPU = () => {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var data = imgData.data;
        //Only Check R count
        pixelCount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.byteLength; i = i + 4) {
            if (data[i] < 229) {
                pixelCount++;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('pixelCount').innerHTML = 'PixelCount in CPU for R channel is :' + pixelCount + ' i.e. (' + pixelCount/(img.width * img.height) + ')'; 
    };

    var fileLoader = document.getElementById('fileLoader');
    fileLoader.oninput = (e) => {
        img = null;
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var fr = new FileReader();
        if (file.type) {
            img = new Image();
            fr.onload = (evt) => {
                var blob = new Blob( [evt.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
                var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
                img.src = imageUrl;
                img.onload = () => {
                    checkCPU();
                    checkGPU();
                };
            };
            fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        } else {
            console.log('Invalid File')
        }
    };
});
```

```html
    <input type="file" id="fileLoader" />
    <hr/>
    <h1 id="pixelCount"></h1>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script id="new-vs" type="not-js">

        attribute vec2 vertices;
        varying vec2 texcoord;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(vertices.x, vertices.y * -1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            texcoord = vertices.xy * .5 + .5;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="pixelcount-fs" type="not-js">
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
    const int {imageWidth};
    const int {imageHeight};
    void main() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x) {
            vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(x, y) + 0.5 / vec2(imageWidth, imageHeight));
            if (color.r < 229.0 / 255.0) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        }
        int normalizedVal = (count / (imageHeight * imageWidth));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(normalizedVal);
    }
    </script>

    <script id="show-fs" type="not-js">
            precision mediump float;
            uniform sampler2D u_texture;
            uniform float pixelCount;
            void main() {
                float index = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(0.0, 0.0)).r;
                if (index == pixelCount) {
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(index, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                } else {
                    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, index, 0.0, 1.0);
                }
            }  
    </script>
```

I am working on a project where I need to get the pixel count for pixel values less than some number.
For eg :

```
var count = width * height;
var pixelCount = 0;
var neglectIntensityValue = 229;
for (var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
    var currIntensity = buffer[i];
    if(currIntensity < neglectIntensityValue) pixelCount++;
}
console.log('PixelCount', pixelCount);
```

As you can see in the above code, I am getting the pixelCount for all the pixel values that are less than 229. This works absolutely fine , but this is very time taking process. Can it be done in GPU?
While I know we shouldn't use GPU loops but am wondering whether its possible. And if yes can I get some pseudocode?

Edit : 
If you refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/9amgpndt/) I found that we can get the count if it is a smaller image of 256 x 1, but how to do the same in case of img.width and img.height

```
<script id="max-fs" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  vec4 maxColor = vec4(0);

  // we know the texture is 256x1 so just go over the whole thing
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    // compute centers of pixels
    vec2 uv = vec2((float(i) + 0.5) / 256.0, 0.5);

    // get max value of pixel
    maxColor = max(maxColor, texture2D(u_texture, uv));
  }

  gl_FragColor = maxColor;
}
</script>
```

And this is what my shader looks like but doesn't work:

```
<script id="pixelCount-fs" type="not-js">
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    vec4 colorInfo = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
    if (colorInfo.r < 0.89453125) {
        discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(colorInfo.r), 1.0);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just loop over all the pixels?

```
  uniform sampler2D data;
  const int width = ${imageData.width};
  const int height = ${imageData.height};
  void main() {
    float count = 0.0;
    vec2 size = vec2(width, height);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        float data = texture2D(data, (vec2(x, y) + 0.5) / size).r;
        if (data < 229.0 / 255.0) {
          count += 1.0;
        }
      }
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
        mod(count, 256.0),
        mod(floor(count / 256.0), 256.0),
        mod(floor(count / 256.0 / 256.0), 256.0),
        floor(count / 256.0 / 256.0 / 256.0)) / 255.0;
  }
}
```

Then draw 1 pixel and read it

```
  const result = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);
  const count = result[0] + 
                result[1] * 256 + 
                result[2] * 256 * 256 +
                result[3] * 256 * 256 * 256;
```

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  
  // make a random image
  const imageData = (function(width, height) {
    const size = width * height;
    const data = new Uint8Array(size);
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      const v = Math.random() * 256 | 0;
      data[i] = v;
      count += v < 229 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return { width, height, data, count };
  }(400, 200));

  const dataTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, dataTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D,
      0,  // mip level
      gl.LUMINANCE,  // internal format
      imageData.width,
      imageData.height,
      0,  // border
      gl.LUMINANCE,  // format
      gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
      imageData.data);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
    gl_Position = position;
  }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  precision highp float;
  uniform sampler2D data;
  const int width = ${imageData.width};
  const int height = ${imageData.height};
  void main() {
    float count = 0.0;
    vec2 size = vec2(width, height);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        float data = texture2D(data, (vec2(x, y) + 0.5) / size).r;
        if (data < 229.0 / 255.0) {
          count += 1.0;
        }
      }
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
        mod(count, 256.0),
        mod(floor(count / 256.0), 256.0),
        mod(floor(count / 256.0 / 256.0), 256.0),
        floor(count / 256.0 / 256.0 / 256.0)) / 255.0;
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.activeTeture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    data: dataTexture,
  });
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);
  
  // draw 1 point
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
  
  const result = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, result);
  const count = result[0] + 
                result[1] * 256 + 
                result[2] * 256 * 256 +
                result[3] * 256 * 256 * 256;
  const size = imageData.width * imageData.height;
  console.log('CPU count:', imageData.count, 'of', size);
  console.log('GPU count:', count, 'of', size);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

note: whether or not this is faster than doing it in JavaScript is probably something you have to test. There's the overhead of sending the image to the GPU.

Also depending on how big the image is it might make sense to look at parts. For example counting every 16x16 area into a texture, and then adding the results (on the gpu in a separate draw call). The GPU can parallelize writing multiple pixels but in the example above it's only writing a single pixel so there is nothing to parallelize.

Also also it would be faster to count all channels R,G,B,A at once then just one channel R.

PS: If you want the code above to work on Safari you'll need to workaround [Safari's bugs](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197592) and provide data (a buffer) and setup the attribute for the 1 point

Comment: This example works only if  width and height doesn't change ever. But in my case everytime I get image of different dimensions. So instead of `const int imageWidth, imageHeight`, I have to use `uniform float imageWidth,imageHeight` but it throws one expected error i.e. `'y' : Loop index cannot be compared with non-constant expression`

Comment: correct, loops have to be constant integers in GLSL ES 1.0 so build your shaders on the fly. ``function  makeShaderSource(width, height) { return `... const int ${width}; const int height ${height}; ....`; }``;  in GLSL ES 3.0 (WebGL2) that limit goes away

Comment: ok I can do that but another problem is gl_FragColor always contains a vec4 and the values ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 only. How can I get the integer count to be available to me in this case.

Comment: Like it says in the answer, make 1x1 pixel floating point texture and render to it. You could also multiply the count into parts `gl_FragColor = vec4(count % 256.0 / 255.0, ((count / 256.0) % 256) / 255.0, ((count / 65536.0) % 256.0) / 255.0, ...);`; then read pixels the 1 pixels and put the parts back together `count = data[0] + data[1] * 256 + data[2] * 65536 ...`;

Comment: Updated the question, added the solution that I tried, but the CPU and GPU values are not matching. It should bring a red as output, but green color is coming.  `float index = texture(u_texture, vec2(0.0, 0.0)).r;
                if (index == pixelCount) {
                    fcolor = vec4(index, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                } else {
                    fcolor = vec4(0.0, index, 0.0, 1.0);
                }`

Comment: You should revert your changes and ask a new question. You asked about WebGL. I answered about WebGL. now you've changed the question to WebGL2 which would have a different answer.

Comment: Ok I will change my shaders to webgl 1 in my question shortly . I don’t need webgl2 now as I think the concept will be similar only

Comment: Changed to WebGL1